# Loop with two variables at once in Bash

Tags: bash, loops, command-line, ffmpeg, muxer

I have two file types with the same filenames in one directory:

```
file1.ts
file1.ec3
file2.ts
file2.ec3
```

and I need to make a loop which would process pair of files at once (file1.ts + file1.ec3).
Then the loop needs to be restarted with second pair (file2.ts + file2.ec3).

Here is my code:

```
for i in *.ts; do
    for e in *.ec3; do
        ffmpeg -i "$i" -i "$e" -map 0:v -map 1:a -codec copy "${i%.ts}_DD+.ts";
    done;
done
```

But when the first cycle ends it tries to process file1.ts + file2.ec3 and brakes everything...

How can I make it work properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
for file in *.ts; do
    [ -f "${file%.ts}.ec3" ] &&
        ffmpeg -i "$file" -i "${file%.ts}.ec3" -map 0:v -map 1:a \
            -codec copy "${file%.ts}_DD+.ts"
done
```